# How to get visas for Cambodia and Laos?

Tags: visas, pakistani-citizens, cambodia, laos

I am a Pakistani national and I have valid tourist visas for Thailand and Malaysia. I am also planning to visit Cambodia and Laos, but neither country has an embassy or consulate in my country.

I am not sure if I need visas and, if I do, whether I can apply online for both Cambodia and Laos.

My travel agent says I don't need a visa for Cambodia, but I want to be sure that is correct.

Comment: Related: *[Tips for getting a visa when there's no embassy in one's country of residence](/questions/3455)* and *[What if passport is lost and home country has no diplomatic presence?](/questions/83523)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a Pakistani citizen you need a visa to enter Cambodia and Laos. Also you may not be eligible to apply online for these both countries.

**Cambodia**

You are not eligible to apply online for a Cambodian visa. Therefore you need a proper visa from a Cambodian embassy or consulate.

Source: [Kingdom Of Cambodia](https://www.evisa.gov.kh/)

Further since you have a valid visa from Thailand, you can apply for a Cambodian visa from The Royal Embassy of Cambodia in Thailand. All details regarding visa and application procedure can be obtained from [Cambodia Mission Worldwide](http://www.embassyofcambodia.org/other_embassies.html), and simply contact the royal embassy of Cambodia in Thailand.

Moreover your travel agent saying you don't need any Cambodian visa is totally wrong. You can also visit [Visa Policy of Cambodia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Cambodia) to confirm that you definitely need a visa and are not eligible for an online visa either.

**Laos**

You are also not eligible to apply for an online visa for Laos.

Source: [Laos Visa On Arrival](http://www.tourismlaos.org/show.php?Cont_ID=348)

Similarly you have a valid visa from Thailand, you can also apply for a Laos visa from Thailand. You can contact Laos embassy in Thailand from  [Laos Embassies And Consulate Abroad](http://www.tourismlaos.org/show.php?Cont_ID=349) and can get all requirements regarding the application procedure.

Comment: @pnuts I have personaly called Cambodian embassy Thailand 5 months ago, they are no longer offering VOA for Pakistani nationals. From Thailand it is really easy just need 35 USD, hotel booking and itinerary but i didnt apply from Thailand. Timatic is not fully upto date, thats why I always use official Embassy websites :)

Comment: @pnuts the same is for Laos , when you call Laos embassy they demans the same flight non refundable itinerary, hotel booking and fee, therefore timatic is not always up to date. Dont believe me email those embassies and ask whether Pakistani nationals need a visa for Laos and Cambodia

Comment: @pnuts ok I am going to sleep, lets do 1 thing here: email both embassies  and ask if Pakistani Citizen are eligible for VOA or they have to have a porper visa, we will discuss after you receive an answer :), it would take a minute only :)

Comment: @pnuts  While I can't back it up with links to official sources, my understanding is the same as Ali Awan, that Pakistani nationals can not get VOAs for Cambodia or Laos (or Thailand, or Malaysia)

Comment: As noted by Moeen, according to www.evisa.gov.kh, Pakistani nationals can now apply for e-visas for Cambodia. The restriction by Laos remains.

Comment: @Ali Awan, IATA timatic is a real time reference database. Airlines and immigration worldwide use it to check visa regulations for all countries applicable to all nationalities. And for that reaoson for it to work it must always be be up-to-date. I don't know how Timatic is updated etc but I doubt if the info available on Timatic is ever out of date. This issue needs a thread of its own.

Comment: @pnuts &Ali Awan, just to add: it is not uncommon to find discrepancies between information provided by a country's embassy and that country's actual visa regulations. I have often been in a situation where embassies were unaware of the changes in their country's visa regulations and either flatly refused to acknowledge their mistake or inquired from back home before correcting their view. Sometimes two embassies give contradictory info about visa requirements etc. This happens where things don't work smoothly, and I count Cambodia as one of those states where bureaucracy is erratic.

Answer (score 5):

I emailed the Cambodian e-visa service to ask if Pakistani citizens are eligible for e-visa. This is what I received in reply:

> Dear sir/madam,
>   We would like to inform you that E-visa is available for any 
>   nationalities. If you want to apply for an e-visa, please go to 
>   www.evisa.gov.kh for more information relating to the entry port and the 
>   required documents.
>   Thank you

So I guess Pakistani citizens can now apply for e-visa for Cambodia.

Comment: This is also confirmed by text on www.evisa.gov.kh.

Answer (score 3):

I have visited Cambodia three times and Laos five times in last 15 years on a Pakistani passport. A visa was available on arrival when I first visited in 2002 and 2006, while later it became compulsory to obtain it beforehand. I have twice obtained my visas in Bangkok and once in KL.

Answer (score 1):

Cambodian e-visa was not available to Pakistan passport holders for the last few years but it seems that Pakistanis are now allowed to apply for one. You may want to inquire directly from the official website of the Cambodian e-visa.

Cambodian visa regime and its application is rather erratic. To be on the safe side you should apply at Cambodian embassy in Bangkok or Kuala Lumpur, depending on your itinerary, and obtain a sticker visa before flying to Cambodia (As a Pakistan passport holder you can only enter Cambodia by air - no land border crossings allowed).

As for Laos, there is no e-visa as far as I know. Apply at the Laotian embassy in BKK or KUL.