# How can I find out if I need a visa to visit a certain country?

Tags: visas, international-travel

I'm a national of country XYZ who wants to visit the state ABC for the purpose of tourism. How can I find out if I will need a visa?

> NB: this is intended as a canonical/wiki question

Comment: @JonathanReez good answer, but timatic is not always fully uptodate

Comment: This question is highly problematic. Narrower canonical questions have already been criticised, this one is even broader. And of course, it's not really a Q&A, it's just a way to post a link to Timatic without actually answering any question someone actually has (so it's basically useless as a target for duplicates). Even if we disregard all the issues with Timatic, this means that this question (and everything else linking to it) would become useless as soon as Timatic is down, blocked by a paywall or something. That's not how SE is supposed to work.

Comment: Incidentally, we already have questions like that, e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/is-there-any-online-resource-that-can-tell-me-what-visa-rules-are-for-passport-h/12944#12944 Also, this had been discussed on meta more than a year ago: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3417/can-we-should-we-mark-every-visa-question-as-a-duplicate/3418#3418

Comment: here are examples where timatic fails [example 1](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85093/transiting-through-kuala-lumpur-two-different-carriers/85098#85098), [example 2](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84477/how-to-get-visas-for-cambodia-and-laos/84479#84479), therefore we cannot simply rely on tamatic

Comment: +1, but please check canonicals with Joe first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most reliable options is to query the [Timatic database](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC):

[image]

You enter your nationality, your destination and (optionally) other details such as your transit airports and duration of stay. The next page will then show if you need a visa or not, as well as additional requirements:

[image]

Airline agents will use the same information to decide if you can be allowed on-board, so if the Timatic website says you're okay to go, you can also be sure the airline won't have any issues.

Answer (score 4):

Online, you can often look to Wikipedia. For example, [Visa Requirements for NZ Citizens](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Visa_requirements_for_New_Zealand_citizens).

Alternatively, there's sites like [VisaHQ](https://www.visahq.com/), which allows you to specify your passport and the destination country, and find out what  you need.

However, if in doubt, the embassy for that country, or their respective website is always the best port of call.

It's also important to note that a visa does not guarantee entrance to a country - ultimately it can be dependent on the airline you use (they need to check if you need evidence of departure, for example in some countries) and also, the border guard on duty when you enter, has some say as to whether you're permitted to enter.  Your history (past countries visited, criminal record) can also affect your eligibility.